# How to make Named work at boot to resolve DNS queries (possible crontab entry)

Tags: dns, centos7

Hi I'm a student at Seneca in the OPS335 right now and I'm new here, so basically I setup a new DNS server on my Centos7 machine and got it working perfectly, all the zones in named.conf are setup right, all the records and files are in place, the ifcfg-ens33 and resolv.conf files are all set with the right 'IPs', 'DNS1' and 'namserver', 'search' parameters. The service is enabled to start at boot, but when i get to my terminal and try pinging google.ca or a host command it will not resolve until i manually restart the services even though they are active. Iptables are set to allow it in and out via its port (53). If anyone knows how to fix this please help me out, otherwise i had another idea with crontab.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

So in order for me to make what i have work is to manually restart the iptables libvirtd and named services in that order, so i made a small script to do this and then tried adding it to crontab after testing it in terminal. I made it to restart the service at reboot and it works in the terminal, but when i try adding it to crontab with a new line at the end as :

@reboot /namedrestart2.bash

it does not work, named boots and is active and enabled, but it still will not resolve DNS queries.

I am not sure if i have the right PATH and SHELL set for crontab mine is :

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

SHELL=/bin/sh

MAILTO=root

The main result that i want is for named to boot properly so i dont have to go through this restart service hassle.

Again any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Inspect your logfiles to understand why things did not work on boot correctly...

Comment: did you check `firewalld` rather than `iptables` thats the default on CO7. `service stop firewalld`

Comment: my logfiles only tell me it had a bad file, which i deleted and have been using manually, and i have firewalld disabled and am using iptables as per my instructors instructions.